# alternative words to ask a question

Tags: word-usage

It is said that a good way to learn English is to summarize a group of similar expressions. First time I read that, first thing came up in my mind is the expression of asking a question.

Here is a list of alternative words to ask, as far as what I can find.

> post a question
>
> pose a question
>
> propose a question
>
> put forward a question
>
> raise a question
>
> bring forward a question
>
> create a question
>
> make a question

Google Ngram seems to accept all of them.

[image]

In my [another SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344928/714660) I said

> About 1 hour ago, I **created a question** ...

Are those expressions interchangeable in this context?

Comment: **About one hour ago, I asked a question** would sound best, I think.

Comment: Only be careful about making this a habit. If you put several different but similar words in a sentence you often make it less understandable. "I want to pose, ask, suggest, raise a question." It's actually harder to understand than "I want to ask a question." This is because it forces your audience to understand each word and spend time working out if they really do mean the same.

Comment: The chart shows you how much each was used for the time period. "ask a question" was used about 10 times as much as the others combined. Go with the most popular choice that means the right thing until you learn the nuances of the other phrases. Note that "raise a question" and "pose a question" are roughly equal at the end of the time period, and the others are barely used in comparison.